# How do I upgrade BIOS on my Asrock E350M1

Tags: bios, usb-flash-drive

I've downloaded the [latest BIOS](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/E350M1/?cat=Download&os=BIOS) for the Asrock E350M1 motherboard to have DDR3 1333 compatibility.

I followed [the instructions](http://www.asrock.com/support/BIOSUI.asp?cat=BIOS):

1. I formatted my USB drive with `sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdb1` and `df -T` said the drive is now "vfat" (I'm on GNU/Linux).
2. I unzipped the archive in the drive.
3. I rebooted and entered the utility.

No luck. It still doesn't find a compatible drive. Yet, the BIOS menu took a longer time than usual to open, as if it had been doing something (which it didn't with non-FAT32 drives).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The file (e.g. E350M12.10) must be **the only file** in the (root of) the drive.

Comment: This should be added as a comment or added to your question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually, this *is* the answer by the author, talking to themselves from a third person perspective. @suspectus